# Debain no longer booting after apt-get remove upstart

Tags: debian, boot, upstart

I can no longer boot my server up. I get the following issue:

```
Loading, please wait...
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
# _
```

and my system just sits there. It occured after I removed upstart

```
apt-get remove upstart
```

and then rebooted because I always reboot the system after I run any apt-get command.

When I run the system in recovery mode I get a kernel panic, **so I cannot boot into recovery mode.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot off a Live CD.  You can either try booting into rescue mode (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-boot-ubuntu-linux-rescue-mode/) and try repairing your system or you can try and do a re-install but don't format the file systems so you won't overwrite any data you've written to disk.

Either way, you can backup your data using the rescue mode.

Comment: At what point does it panic?  During boot off Live CD?  What Live CD are you booting off of?

Comment: When I am in grub, I select the second option, and then the log reads kernel panic.

Comment: grub of your install or the live cd?

Comment: What can I do with my data from the live cd. How can I save it. And how can I save the apache settings and things like that. Please help me. If you either of you can solve this you can get 4 bitcoins if you so please.

Comment: Grub of my install

Comment: Use the Live CD rescue mode, not repair mode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1425/discussion-between-acase-and-macintosh264)

Comment: YOU ARE AWSOME. I am back up and running! Thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: Finally have enough rep. Upvote

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, I have not had any issues, and I can now use upstart's full abilities, so thanks again ACase, I am greatly in debt to you. Contact me if you need anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Like ACase said, boot off a Live CD.  Then, mount your data:

cat /proc/partitions to find what partitions available
mkdir /mnt/my_disk
mount -t   /mnt/my_disk
chroot /mnt/my_disk
apt-get install upstart
umount /mnt/my_disk
restart without live CD

Comment: What can I do with my data from the live cd. How can I save it. And how can I save the apache settings and things like that. Please help me. If you either of you can solve this you can get 4 bitcoins if you so please.

Comment: You can scp it off to another host if you enable networking.  Or just stick in a USB stick and cp the files off.

Comment: and what about appache settings, my php cli extensions, and other stuff. And do you think I should cp it to my second internal HD, and if so how can I mount it.